# Casting List<SomeClass> to List<object>

Tags: .net

Can we cast `List<SomeClass>` in to `List<object>` int .net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with a simple cast.  They are two different types, and there is no inheritance relationship between the two types.  But you can do something like this:

```
foreach (Object item in MyList.Cast<object>() )
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: Hey, neat! @Jayantha: I believe these are the docs for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Comment: I don't think you need the .Cast<object> if you're specifying object as the type in the foreach...

Comment: @Massif - true.  This is more useful casting from child type to parent type/interface, but I suspect that's what is really happening here and object is just a placeholder for the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can cast an array that way, but not a list.

As `SomeClass` can always be cast to `object`, you can use the `Cast` method to create the list:

```
List<object> list = someClassList.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example this should work

```
List<int> intList=new List<int>();
intList.Add(1);
intList.Add(2);
List<object> listObject = intList.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
List<object> listObj = myList.ConvertAll(item => (object)item);
```

I made a simple Person class like so:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Made a list:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Al",  Score=97.3});
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob",  Score = 99.2});
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Charlie", Score=55.333});
```

And did the conversion like this:

```
List<object> listOfObjects = people.ConvertAll(item => (object)item);
```

Seemed to work well enough.  But perhaps I'm missing something here.  Obviously, I've created a new list here.  Thoughts?